# How to re-stream h265 RTSP stream using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have written a small piece of code to re-stream camera RTSP stream on Nginx stream server using FFMPEG.

Everything working fine, my re-stream RTSP on to Nginx stream server using following FFMPEG command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i 'rtsp://212.78.10.88:554/stream' -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream
```

My basic problem is H265 and H265+. FFMPEG failed to re-stream H265 format streams. I tried differently command params but no luck.

Any body know how to re-stream H265 and + in FFMPEG?

Comment: You will have to stream HLS or DASH - FLV can't take H.265 - see http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue to re-stream h265 stream.

I just used following arguments in command to solve this issue.

```
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p
```

and final command is:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i 'rtsp://212.78.10.88:554/stream' -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream
```